# Why don't I have to Base64 encode this output?

Tags: php

I am writing a script in PHP that does the very common task of reading a binary file from disk and outputting it as a file download to the browser.

```
header('Content-Length: '.$file['fileSize']);                   
header('Content-type: '.$file['mimeType']);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file['title']);
set_time_limit(0);
$chunksize = 1 * (1024 * 1024);

$handle = fopen($file['path'], 'r'); 
$buffer = ''; 
while (!feof($handle)) { 
  $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize); 
  echo $buffer; 
  ob_flush(); 
  flush(); 
} 
fclose($handle);
```

This works - no problems. But my question...

I've read in various places that in some cases you need to Base64 encode binary data before sending it over the network because binary data may have characters that can't be represented in the default character set.

What I can't quite grasp is this - why don't I have to do this in my case?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: you only need mime/base64 if the underlying protocol isn't 8bit clean, e.g. SMTP, which is only 7bit. http is more modern and will handle 8bit data no problem.